# Passing dataframes as argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have a function that aplies some transformations in a dataset. I want to place each operation in a different function, so that the code becomes more modular and the main function does not require a large number of line of code.

```
def do_somethings(df):
    df = do_a(df)
    df = do_b(df)
    df = do_c(df)
    return df
```

But is it a good idea? Because each time I pass the dataframe as argument python makes a copy of it, right? And my dataframe is large. Doesn't that imply performance?

I really don't want to my function have 100+ lines of code.

Comment: No, a called function doesn't get a copy. The calling code passes a reference to the parameter, not a copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the default is not, that a copy of your dataframe will be created, because for that the copy() method exists.

But if it creates a copy, you can probably use the copy() method and specify deep=False.
In the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) it is explained that with deep=False for the copy, neither data nor indices are being copied, which should therefore not decrease the peformance.